# Change parent window location from popup

Tags: html, popup, window

I am trying to make some website and would like to ask some questions.
The main file for the website is main.asp.
In main.asp, I inserted notice.jpg file as a pop up window.

I would like to make that, if I click the pop up window, then the pop up window disappear and the new big window(www.charming.or.kr/jeju/) show up.
Can anyone help me on this? 
The following is part of my source.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=euc-kr" />
<title><!--#include file="../include/title.asp"--></title>
<style type="text/css">
@import url(../css/comm.css);
</style>
<script language='javascript'> 
function OpenWin(dest) 
{ 
posy = screen.Height/2 - 100; 
posx = screen.Width /2 - 200; 

StartWin = window.open(dest, 
"notice_popup","toolbar=no,channelmode=no,left="+posx+",top="+posy+",location=no,directories=no,w    idth=743,height=720,resizable=no,menubar=no,scroll=no"); 
} 


</script> 

</head>

<body onload="OpenWin('../img/main/Notice.jpg')" >
```

Answer (score 2):

In your new window you can refer to your original window by using `window.opener` which is a direct reference to your original. You can thus use

```
window.opener.location.href = newURL;
```

Comment: thanks for your kindness.  Please tell me where the location("window.opener.location.href = newURL; "
 is

Comment: If you want to change the URL when the user clicks the image, you'd have to setup a small html page containing only the image and have a click handler that sets the url.